# Why does ruby recognise a method outside of a class, but not inside?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to build a simple language translating program. I imported the 'language_converter' gem to aid with this goal. I wrote the following code:

```
require 'language_converter'

class Translator
    def initialize
        @to = 'ja';  
        @from = 'en';   
    end

    def translate text
        lc(text, @to,@from)
    end
end

#puts lc('welcome to Japan!', 'ja','en');
 
t = Translator.new

p t.translate('welcome to Japan!');
```

This code results in the error: `undefined method 'lc' for #<Translator:0x0000000101167a90 @to="ja", @from="en"> (NoMethodError)`
However, when i uncomment the code on line 15, ruby can access the `lc` method and return some japanese. Does anyone know why the method is 'defined' outside of the class but not inside?

Edit: the [language-converter](https://rubygems.org/gems/language-converter) gem is not my own. also, I cannot find the source code on its homepage.

I have also tried adding two semicolons before the `lc` method like so: `::lc(text, @to,@from)`. This results in the error: `syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting constant`

Comment: Is `language_converter` your own code? Or is it a 3rd party library? If it is your own code, will you please [edit] your question to show it?

Comment: What happens if you do `::lc(...)` inside the `translate()` method?

Comment: If you really need to: `TOPLEVEL_BINDING.receiver.lc(...)`. But you should probably not use the gem in the first place.

Comment: _"I cannot find the source code"_ – you can extract it via `gem unpack language-converter` to the current directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gem is more than 10 years old and only has one method. And that method is implemented as a class method.

You are properly better off with just rewriting that method in your application with a modern Ruby syntax and proper error handling.

For reference, this it how `lib/language_converter.rb` in the gem looks like:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'rubygems'
require "uri"
require 'json'

class UnSupportedLanguage < RuntimeError

  def initialize(message='')
    @msg = "not supported."
  end
end


  def self.lc( text, to, from='en' )

    begin

      uri = URI.parse("http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get")

      response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"q" => text,"langpair"=>"#{from.to_s.downcase}|#{to.to_s.downcase}", "per_page" => "50"})

      json_response_body = JSON.parse( response.body )

      if json_response_body['responseStatus'] == 200
        json_response_body['responseData']['translatedText']
      else
        puts json_response_body['responseDetails']
        raise StandardError, response['responseDetails']
      end
    rescue UnSupportedLanguage
      raise UnSupportedLanguage.new
    rescue => err_msg
      puts "#{err_msg}"
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know why the method is 'defined' outside of the class but not inside?

The method lookup algorithm in Ruby is relatively simple. (At least it was until the introduction of [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Module.html#method-i-prepend) / `Module#prepend_features`, so let's ignore that for now). Here's how it goes:

1. Retrieve the value of the hidden `class` pointer of the receiver.
2. Check whether the method table contains the method.

   1. If yes, you are done.
   2. If not, continue to step #3.
3. Retrieve the value of the superclass pointer.

   1. If there is no superclass, go to step #4.
   2. If there is a superclass, repeat from step #2.
4. Start the algorithm from the beginning with the message selector `method_missing`, passing the name of the original message and its arguments as arguments.

And that's it. This is always guaranteed to terminate because the top-level class always has a method named `method_missing`.

Now, you might ask: but wait, what about singleton classes?

The answer is: the hidden `class` pointer of an object points to its singleton class, and the singleton class's superclass pointer points (directly or indirectly) to the "actual" class.

Now, you might ask: but wait, why doesn't [`Object#class`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-class) return the singleton class, then?

The answer is: `Object#class` doesn't directly return the hidden `class` pointer. Instead, it follows the superclass chain until it finds the first "normal" class.

Now, you might ask: but wait, what about mixins using [`Module#include`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Module.html#method-i-include)?

The answer is: `Module#include` (or rather `Module#append_features`) synthesizes a new class (sometimes called an *include class*) which shares its method table, constant table, class variable table, and instance variable table with the module and makes that class the superclass of the class the module is mixed into (and it does that recursively for all modules that were mixed into that module).

This "trick" of inserting singleton classes and include classes into the normal class chain means that operations which happen *often* are *fast* and *simple*, namely *method lookup*. The *complexity* is moved to operations like calling `Object#class` or `Module#include`, but that's okay because those are only rarely called and typically only happen during debugging or application startup.

So, now we know the two pieces of information required to figure out whether or not a method is callable:

1. We need to know in which method table, i.e. in which module the method is defined.
2. We need to know what the chain of superclasses is for the receiver.

Once we know those two things, we can check whether the module the method is defined in is part of the lookup chain of the receiver.

Answering #1 is easy. We can use [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-method) to create a [`Method`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Method.html) object (a reflective proxy) for the method we want to know about, and then we can use [`Method#owner`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Method.html#method-i-owner) to ask the method where it is defined.

So, we *know* that calling the method at the top-level works, which means we can ask the top-level object for the method:

```ruby
m = method(:lc)
```

And now we can ask the method for its owner:

```ruby
m.owner
#=> #<Class:#<Object:0x0000000104c3cd00>>
```

Uh. Okay. That's not very helpful. What this tells us is the following:

- The method is defined in a singleton class.
- The object the singleton class belongs to is a direct instance of `Object`.
- And that's it.

So, all we know is that the method is defined in a singleton class of some object. We have to dig a bit deeper.

One possibility would be to use [`Method#source_location`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Method.html#method-i-source_location) to find where the source code of the method is. However, this not guaranteed to work: for example, methods in C extensions for YARV or methods written in Java in JRuby or TruffleRuby do not have "(Ruby) source code", so this method will return `nil`.

In this case, the method will work and will give the path to the file inside the Gem and the line number where the method is defined.

However, let's see if we can find out more. Every object in Ruby has the [`Object#inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-inspect) method, whose purpose it is to provide human-readable debug information. Well, we are debugging and we are humans (I assume), so let's see what we can get.

We shouldn't be too hopeful, because for a typical singleton method, that will look something like this:

```ruby
foo = Object.new
def foo.bar(a, b = 23, *c, d, e:, f: 42, **g, &h) end

b = foo.method(:bar)
b.inspect
#=> '#<Method: #<Object:0x0000000109053ca0>.bar(a, b=..., *c, d, e:, f: ..., **g, &h) /path/to/source/file.rb:2>'
```

Which basically just gives us the same information we can also get from `Method#owner`, `Method#source_location`, and [`Method#parameters`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Method.html#method-i-parameters), but in a nice and compact way.

But let's try it anyway:

```ruby
m.inspect
#=> '#<Method: main.lc(text, to, from=...) /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/language-converter-1.0.0/lib/language_converter.rb:14>'
```

That's interesting! The method is actually displayed as `main.lc(text, to, from=...)` and not something like `#<Object:0x0000000109053ca0>.lc(text, to, from=...)`. So, what is `main`?

`main` is the *informal* name of the so-called *top-level object*, i.e. the object which is `self` in code that is at the top-level of a script, not enclosed in any module:

```ruby
toplevel = self

toplevel.inspect
#=> 'main'
```

This means that the method `lc` is defined in the singleton class of `main`, something like this:

```ruby
def self.lc(text, to, from='en')
  # …
end
```

And this, finally, explains *why* you can't call it from anywhere but the top-level:

```ruby
lc
```

works, because the implicit receiver `self` here is `main`, the hidden class pointer of `main` points to `main.singleton_class`, and that's where `lc` is defined.

But

```ruby
t.translate(…)
```

doesn't work, because inside `translate`, where `lc` is called without a receiver, the implicit receiver `self` is `t` whose method lookup chain looks something like this:

1. `t`'s hidden class pointer which is `t.singleton_class`.
2. `t.singleton_class`'s hidden superclass pointer which is `t.singleton_class.superclass` which is `t.class` which is `Translator`.
3. `Translator`'s hidden superclass pointer which is `Translator.superclass` which is `Object`.
4. `Object`'s hidden superclass pointer which is `Object`'s include class for `Kernel`.
5. `Object`'s include class for `Kernel`'s hidden superclass pointer which is `Object.superclass` which is `BasicObject`.

You can roughly approximate this by using Ruby Reflection:

```ruby
t.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> [
#     #<Class:#<Translator:0x00000001023c8ef0>>,
#     Translator,
#     Object,
#     Kernel,
#     BasicObject
#   ]
```

As you can see, `main.singleton_class` does not appear anywhere in the method lookup chain, and thus, `lc` will not be found.

If you really, absolutely, have to use this method, there are a few possible workarounds.

You could grab a reference to the method and keep it around for later:

```ruby
LC = method(:lc)

class Translator
  # …

  def translate text
    LC.(text, @to, @from)
  end
end
```

You could grab a reference to `main` and keep it around for later:

```ruby
MAIN = self

class Translator
  # …

  def translate text
    MAIN.lc(text, @to, @from)
  end
end
```

In fact, Ruby has a pre-defined constant for the whole top-level [`Binding`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Binding.html) called [`TOPLEVEL_BINDING`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+global+constants). You can get the top-level object using the [`Binding#receiver`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Binding.html#method-i-receiver) method:

```ruby
class Translator
  # …

  def translate text
    TOPLEVEL_BINDING.receiver.lc(text, @to, @from)
  end
end
```

This is a weird way to define a method. It makes this method very hard and annoying to use.

Typically, methods like this, which are meant to be called at the top-level with an implicit receiver are defined as instance methods of [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Kernel.html). Some methods you probably recognize are [`Kernel#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) or [`Kernel#require`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require).

In fact, by the way the method is indented in the code, I am not even sure this was intended.

Which brings us to your other question:

> I cannot find the source code on its homepage

As shown above, you can always find the location of the source code of a method by simply asking it:

```ruby
m.source_location
#=> '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/language-converter-1.0.0/lib/language_converter.rb:14'
```

So, on my system, the source code for `lc` is in the file at the path `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/language-converter-1.0.0/lib/language_converter.rb` starting at line 14. On your system, the path will obviously be slightly different.

The easiest way to get access to the source code of the entire gem would be to use the [`gem open`](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-open) command:

```sh
gem open language-server
```

This will open the whole gem directory in your default editor.

Another command that is sometimes useful is [`gem unpack`](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-unpack) which unpacks an installed gem into the current directory. If you only want to read the source code, that is overkill since the gem is already unpacked into your gem directory when you install it. But if you want to make changes, you obviously shouldn't do this in the gem directory itself.

Please note: if you decide to actually do this and read this gem's source code, *please* do not learn anything from it, except maybe how *not* to write Ruby. It is horrible.